# Rotate UIImageView from Particular side - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation

I want to rotate image (UIImageView) from particular side (for ex. Right Side).

I know through :-

```
float degrees = 20; //the value in degrees
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);
```

but it rotates from center.

I want to rotate my UIImageView from one particular side (i.e. Left side will be at its place, and right side will change its position).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `anchorPoint` property.

```
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);//Top left angle
float degrees = 20; //the value in degrees
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);
```

Do not forget to add `QuartzCore` framework.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want also to keep Right hand point as static and rotate from left, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Could you please clarify it a little bit, or provide an example?

Comment: Well, I made it by using my own logic, thanks a lot for help, your above code helped me at Lot!..

Comment: Nice to hear it. What did you do?

Comment: First I created its mirror image and then I rotated image by 180 degree and then used your code....

Answer (score -1):

Rotate from center and move UIImageView where you will. Result will be the same as rotating from right edge.